# Python Sprite and Classes. How to make a player that canbe updated with WASD in a single class

Tags: python, class

For reference, I am very new to python and coding to general.

The code starting off working, then i had to turn it into classes to get the outcome I want and this is where everything turned bad. The more videos I watched the more broken my code got.

**Below is my class for the player
**
I get one error "'Player' object has no attribute 'x'" -- I was under the impression the
self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (100, 300)) makes an x and y to the sprite.

There is probably other things that are broken or can be done better so please let me konw

```
FPS = 60
VEL = 3

PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT = 62,50
ZOMBIE_WIDTH, ZOMBIE_HEIGHT = 75, 50

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Player Idle', 'tile000.png'))
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(PLAYER_HEIGHT,PLAYER_WIDTH))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (100, 300))

    def update(self, keys_pressed):
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and self.y - VEL > 0: #move forwawrd
            self.y  -= VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and self.x - VEL > 0: #move left
            self.x  -= VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and self.y + VEL + self.height < HEIGHT - 18: #move back
            self.y   += VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and self.x + VEL + self.width < WIDTH: #move right
            self.x  += VEL
```

Below is my main function

```
def main():

    bullets = []

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        player_group.update(keys_pressed)        
        draw_windoww(player)

    pygame.quit()
```

I first tried making the player outsidea class and this working. I just used rects and updated the position the same way I tried now. When I tried that method in classes everything failed. I tried looking at some videos but they approached it from a completly different angle so when I tried to further alter my code I got new errors.

This is the closest I got to what I think is the right idea but wrong exectution

Basically everything c

```
type here
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did anything on pygame, but I think the AttributeError is because of the `update` method.

```
def update(self, keys_pressed):
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and self.y - VEL > 0: #move forwawrd
            self.rect.y  -= VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and self.x - VEL > 0: #move left
            self.rect.x  -= VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and self.y + VEL + self.height < HEIGHT - 18: #move back
            self.rect.y   += VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and self.x + VEL + self.width < WIDTH: #move right
            self.rect.x  += VEL
```

Notice the change from `self.x` and `self.y`, to `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y`

The `Rect` object has `x` and `y` attributes (extract from docs):

```
The Rect object has several virtual attributes which can be used to move and align the Rect:

x,y
top, left, bottom, right
topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
center, centerx, centery
size, width, height
w,h
```

Full docs: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html